# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock is not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

im using ajax pop up . to show the invalid user aceess and then redirecting to home.aspx page, for unauthorised users its redirecting to home.aspx page but pop is not showing that illegal access.

i want to show pop up of illegal access and go to home.aspx or else show the pop up and should not render anything in that page

Pop is not showing

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["LoginUser"].ToString() == "admin" )
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                if (Session["LoginId"] == null)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");

                }
                fillProj();
                fillYear();
                FillUser();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "clentscript", "alert('Illegal Accesss..');", true);
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
this.RegisterStartupScript("scheck", "<script>alert('Illegal Accesss..'); parent.location.href='"Home.aspx'</script>");
```

Or

```
   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "clentscript", "alert('Illegal Accesss..'); parent.location.href='Home.aspx'", true);
```

Comment: still its not showing pop - up , but redirecting to home.aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

Use like below in your else condition.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Illegal Access...');window.location ='Home.aspx';", true);
```

Comment: @krishnasunlightit: you have not copied the code properly. it is working properly on my side. Copy properly and check again

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), 
                  "key", "alert('Illegal Access..')", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "clentscript", "alert('Illegal Accesss..'); parent.location.href='Home.aspx'", true);
```